# PHP Pagination SQL Security

Tags: php, sql, pagination

The following code is SQL vulnerable and I need some help securing it; I am not a wizard with PHP or MySQL.

I have searched around and seen some extremely useful things to do with MySQL real escape string etc but when implemented it just causes a white page

```
    if(!isset($_GET['pg'])) { $page = 1; } else { $page = $_GET['pg']; }
    $select = (($page * 20) - 20); 
$mysql_result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `{$lgsl_config['db']['prefix']}{$lgsl_config['db']['table']}` WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $mysql_where)." ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $select, 20") or die(mysql_error());

<?
$servers = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM data_servers"),0); 
$pages = ceil($servers / 20); 

if(!isset($_GET['pg'])) { $page = 1; } else { $page = $_GET['pg']; }

if($page > 1)
{
$prev = ($page - 1);
echo "<a href='?pg=$prev'>[Inapoi]</a> "; 
}

for($show = 1; $show <= $pages; $show++)
{
if(($page) == $show)
{
echo $show;
}
else
{
echo " <a href='?pg=$show'>[$show]</a> ";
}
}

if($page < $pages)
{ 
$next = ($page + 1); 
echo " <a href='?pg=$next'>[Next]</a> "; 
}
?>
```

Proof that the code is infact vulnerable
on the end of your url just add
?pg=mysql

And you should receive a MySQL syntax error

Comment: You should normally check all inputs of your code, specifically the value of $_GET['pg'] - just check the type and value of the input before passing it into any other portion of code, no matter if it is SQL-related or not.

Comment: So could the following be of any use to me add_slashes,mysql_escape_string,mysql_real_escape_string or would i have to do a preg_match

Comment: Simple fix is to use check cast to integer is_numeric($pg) if not then use default value(1) escape data and then query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't use `$page` directly but you do a mathematical operation on it, if it isn't a numeric value it will be evaluated to 0 if it isn't a number (for example, if it's a string).

I'd suggest anyway to add some controls, just to be sure:

```
if(!isset($_GET['pg']) || !is_numeric($_GET['pg'])) { $page = 1; } else { $page = (int) $_GET['pg']; }
```

In this way you're sure that `$page` holds a integer.

In this case you don't need any escape function, but if you're using directly any other `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable, then you should consider it.

Comment: Thanks Entropy that seems to be doing its job well i have tried ?pg=mysql and i recive no more syntax errors im not sure if there are other ways to test for mysql injections ? But your code seems to have done the job nicely :)

Comment: In this way there can't be mysql injection with that variable, since all kind of strings passed through `$_GET['pg']` are converted into a number.
 
If this helped you, don't forget: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ;)

Comment: Yeah it is no longer displaying any syntax errors unless ofcourse i do ?pg=0

Answer (score 0):

I would check out these links, read them carefully and understand what they are saying to secure your code and server

http://phptutorial.info/?mysql-real-escape-string
http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-blunders/
http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/05/tighten-php-security-functions.html

They helped me when i was learning the security aspect of php coding